# need practice using abstract list functions in scheme

Tags: scheme

Does anyone know any good problems or websites that explain abstract list functions in scheme? For some reason, I have a really hard time understanding abstract list functions and how to use them.

I'm pretty much completely lost when given a problem that has to be solved solely using abstract list functions.

As an example, how would I write a function that finds the maximum element in a list using only abstract list functions?

This is what I have so far:

```
(define (maximum lst)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc) (if (empty? acc) empty
                           (if (< acc e) acc empty))) empty lst))
```

Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work and what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

*(Note that I assume you use Racket due the order of parameters to `foldr` you have in your code; I can adapt it to Scheme if I am wrong about this.)*

I'd go for this:

```
(define (maximum lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
      lst               
      (foldl 
       (lambda (e r) (if (< r e) e r))  ; function to call successively
       (car lst)                        ; initial value for the result r
       (cdr lst))))                     ; list to call function for (element by element)
```

- if the list is empty, return the empty list (or whatever you deem appropriate; necessary because we use `car` afterwards, which will throw an error if the list is empty)
- if not, use `foldl` (for this it doesn't matter if you use `foldl` or `foldr` but `foldl` is more efficient)

  - initialize the result to the first element (`car`)
  - for the rest of the list (`cdr`), call the function with 1. the next element 2. the previous result
  - in the function

    - if e > r, return e, else return r (the returned value is bound to r on the next call, or will be the result of `foldl` when every item has been processed)

Example:

```
(maximum '(3 6 7 1))
```

1. r is initialised to 3 (`car lst`)
2. the function is called with e=6 (next element) and r=3 (initialised value), returns 6
3. the function is called with e=7 (next element) and r=6 ( previous result ), returns 7
4. the function is called with e=1 (next element) and r=7 ( previous result ), returns 7 so 7 becomes the result of `foldl`

Note that Racket has a second way to express this, which might be easier to read because it is closer to a traditional for loop:

```
(define (maximum lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
      '()
      (for/fold ((r (car lst))) ((e (in-list (cdr lst))))
        (if (< r e) e r))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you ask for help to understand why it doesn't work.

```
(define (maximum lst)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc) (if (empty? acc) empty
                           (if (< acc e) acc empty))) empty lst))
```

The problem here is that your initial object is "empty". which means that `acc` is empty at the start of the `fold`. In english your code would be written like this:

Fold on `lst` starting with empty. If `acc` is empty, return empty. Otherwise if `acc` is smaller than `e` return `e` but if not, return empty. The returned value becomes the new `acc`.

Two problems here: As you're starting with empty: acc is always empty. The other problem is here:

```
(if (< acc e) acc empty)
```

Here, you'll return acc if it's smaller than `e` or you will return empty. But if `acc` is smaller than `e` it means that e is bigger. Which mean that you should return `e` and not `empty`.

There is no real reason to check for `empty?` inside your fold.

The fold call would look like this:

```
(foldr (lambda (e acc) (if (< acc e) e acc)) (car lst) (cdr lst))
```

Which translates to fold on the first element of the rest of the list. If acc is smaller than e then return e, otherwise return acc. The returned value will replace acc in the next iteration.

No what you need to do is check for empty lists, and you could have something that looks like that.

```
(define (maximum lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
    (error "Cannot find max from empty list")
    (foldr
      (lambda (e acc)
        (if (< acc e) e acc))
      (car lst)
      lst)))
```

Also one more thing, `foldl` and `foldr` are the same thing except that one starts from the first element and one from the last. In my solution, I haven't tested but as my last argument is the whole list, it shouldn't matter which version of fold you're using.

Comment: 'foldl' is tail recursive, whereas 'foldr' is not. 'foldl' should be preferred where it can be used,

Comment: That's not true, even if one starts from the end (which is foldr). It doesn't mean that it isn't tail recursive. 

`(define (foldr func start lst) (foldl func start (reverse lst)))` It simply does `reverse` the thing first.